# Get current document's Last-Modified date in javascript Date object

Tags: javascript, date, browser

The browser [provides a way to determine a document's last-modified date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.lastModified) by looking at `document.lastModified`.  This property is determined from the HTTP `Last-Modified` header, and is returned as a string.

My goal is to convert this property to a Javascript `Date` object.  Currently I am using

```
var date = new Date(document.lastModified);
```

which successfully parses the string.  However, I am curious as to whether this will work across browsers and across locales.

What is very interesting to me is that the `document.lastModified` represents the same date as the HTTP `Last-Modified` header given, but the strings are not identical.  It seems to me that the browser parses the `Last-Modified` header, converts it to its internal date representation, and then sets `document.lastModified` to a string based on that.  If this is the case, `document.lastModified` is likely to be formatted in a way such that it can be parsed by the Javascript `Date` constructor, as they are both likely using the same locale and formatting rules.  But I've been unable to confirm this for sure.

Comment: Well, according to the MDN _WebKit returns the time string in UTC; Gecko and Internet Explorer return a time in the local timezone_. AFAIK it should work fine with `date` implementations in most browsers, but not sure.

Comment: Right, I figured I can find a way to work around the UTC vs localtime inconsistency as long as the parsing is known to work correctly across browsers and locales.

Comment: In Chrome, it returns the date in UTC, and then tacks on my local timezone, without adjusting the date to my timezone.

Answer (score 3):

You can not `var anotherDateObject = new Date(Date.parse(document.lastModified));`
Just because javascript does not parse a string to Date Object until it contains any separators (like `'/'` or `'-'` other than `empty space` in date part (time part has no problem with `':'`) . Javascript can parse a valid date string with spaces as separator. here it is

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
    var dt = document.lastModified;    
    dt = dt.replace("/", " ");
    dt = dt.replace("/", " ");
    dt = dt.replace("-", " ");
    dt = dt.replace("-", " ");
    // '/' or '-' replcae these separtors with empty space
    // Now your string can be parsed to Date Object
    var anotherDateObject = new Date(Date.parse(dt));
    alert(anotherDateObject + " -- " + anotherDateObject.getHours());        
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would say you need to give a special case for Webkit-based browser until HTML5 Specification finalized.

According to [HTML5 draft](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec//dom.html#dom-document-lastmodified), `document.lastModified` has a very clear requirement for implementation:

> The lastModified attribute, on getting, must return the date and time
>   of the Document's source file's last modification, in the user's local
>   time zone, in the following format:
>
> 1. The month component of the date.
> 2. A "/" (U+002F) character.
> 3. The day component of the date.
> 4. A "/" (U+002F) character.
> 5. The year component of the date.
> 6. A U+0020 SPACE character.
> 7. The hours component of the time.
> 8. A ":" (U+003A) character.
> 9. The minutes component of the time.
> 10. A ":" (U+003A) character.
> 11. The seconds component of the time.

In short words, that is `"MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss"` in the user's *local time zone*. Which means Webkit would be doing it wrong when HTML5 finalized if with same requirement.

Also, the source of modified date is required to conforms to

> The Document's source file's last modification date and time must be derived from relevant features of the networking protocols used, e.g. from the value of the HTTP Last-Modified header of the document, or from metadata in the file system for local files. If the last modification date and time are not known, the attribute must return the current date and time in the above format.

For now, I think, standard per se, every browser can do whatever they like because I can't not find anything about `document.lastModified` in HTML4, XHTML, DOM 2, or DOM 3. I believe it's only defined in HTML5.

Once everyone conforms to standard, there would be no problem even one browser can not parse `"MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss"`, you can always reconstruct it to be ISO 8601, which is accepted in ECMAScript standard. But I think current major browsers can parse the format correctly as local time, which is also expected and standard in ECMAScript.

Comment: Great, thanks for the research.  In this case, perhaps I ought to be using a regular expression to parse `document.lastModified` instead of sending it to `new Date()`.  One of my main original concerns was that the parser would misunderstand the MM/DD/YYYY date if the locale were set to a place which used DD/MM/YYYY dates.  Using a RE would remove this possibility for sure (even though I've not been able to trigger this in any of the major browsers).

Answer (score 2):

Try this ?
`

```
function getLastMod() {
    var lastMod = Date.parse(document.lastModified);
    var now = new Date();
    var diff = (new Date(now.toLocaleString())).getTimezoneOffset() - now.getTimezoneOffset();
    if (!diff) diff = now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
    else diff = 0;
    return lastMod - diff;
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see all major browsers in use today supports this property. The value stored is in local time in the format `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss`.

I think you can use this property across all browsers and locales.

Answer (score 1):

Vis-á-vis livibetter's comment, "For now, I think, standard per se, every browser can do whatever they like because I can't not find anything about document.lastModified in HTML4, XHTML, DOM 2, or DOM 3. I believe it's only defined in HTML5"

I believe "document.lastModified" has been around for a while. I've had it on one site for a few years now (before HTML5). Not that it really matters. If anyone cares (under Windows XP SP3) the browsers I keep around to check pages:

· Chrome 34 still insists in returning the time in UTC (but no local time addition)
· Firefox 28 just ignores the statement "javascript:alert(document.lastModified)"!! :D
· IE8 returned local time (as others have pointed out)
· Opera 12.16 returned local time
· Safari 5.1.7 returned UTC time

At least they're getting the date right; they all returned 11/17/09 on my home page(except Firefox which just continued to ignore)! LOL

It would be nice if reference sources, like W3Schools (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_lastmodified.asp), would add some verbiage along these lines so folks know what to expect when the results are funky.

UPDATE: If you activate Tools | Web Developer | DOM Inspector, Firefox 28 happily executes "javascript:alert(document.lastModified)" and returns local time! What a mish-mash. LOL

Answer (score 1):

**Here is an example:**

```js
<!--
        function makeArray() {
          for (i = 0; i < makeArray.arguments.length; i++)
            this[i] = makeArray.arguments[i];
        }

        function getFullYear(d) {
          var y = d.getYear();
          if (y < 1000) {
            y += 1900
          };
          return y;
        }

        var days = new makeArray("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
        var months = new makeArray("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

        function format_time(t) {
            var Day = t.getDay();
            var Date = t.getDate();
            var Month = t.getMonth();
            var Year = getFullYear(t);
            timeString = "";
            timeString += days[Day];
            timeString += " ";
            timeString += months[Month];
            timeString += " ";
            timeString += Date;
            timeString += ", ";
            timeString += Year;
            return timeString;
          }
// -->

        m = new Date(document.lastModified);
        d = new Date();
        $(function() {
          $('.timestamp').html(format_time(m))
        });
```

```css
.timestamp-wrap { font-size : 22px; font-family : 'Open Sans'; }
.timestamp { color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timestamp-wrap">
  Updated on <span class="timestamp"></span>
</div>
```