# JQuery timeago plugin and lastModified usage

Tags: jquery, timeago

I am using the .timeago plugin from this website: http://timeago.yarp.com/

They have an example there where they display when the page was last modified:

**This page was last modified 25 days ago.**

Does anyone know how to make this work? They don't really say in the website.

Comment: Suggestion, you can use the JS library Moment.js, it is well documented and easy to implement time ago hour! http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow! We can better answer questions that show effort by the asker. In the future, please use Google, documentation (like the bottom of the page you linked to), and other resources to help you before asking. For example, using Google, I found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13408995/1979005), which details how to convert the last modified date into a JS `Date` object. Then, use `[Date.toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)` to make it human readable. Again, welcome!

Comment: @MathSquared11235 Thanks for your help.  I had been searching on Google for about 2hours before I decided to post my question here.  I will use your suggestions and I'm crossing my fingers I'll make this work now.  Again, I really appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could see in the source of the page, the `lastModified` property is available in this form:

```
console.log( document.lastModified );
// prints "07/11/2013 18:32:11"
```

However, I doubt that this works cross-browser aka IE < 9.

Docs for the `lastModified` property, if you want, are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.lastModified).